# Did the Super Predators bring the normal Predators to the hunting planet?

Tags: plot-explanation, predators

In *Predators* (2010) we see the hunting planet of Predators.

A normal Predator (Yautja) from the Jungle Hunter Clan is caprtured by a Super Predator.

[image]

Later in the movie a "normal" Predator is killed by the Super Predator.

[image]

Did the Super Predators bring the normal Predators to the hunting planet to be hunted & are these 2 Types of Predators from same mother Planet?